# ListFormWebPart and Default Values

Tags: list-form

I'm using the `ListFormWebPart` in a custom web part page for creating and editing objects.

One issue, though: when I go to create a new object using the LFWP, it seems to be populating it with some default text (see screenshot below).

I figured that in the case of the URL fields, I could easily find "example.com" and did a find on the whole 14 hive and found no occurrences that match text in that context (was expecting maybe in Resources).  I tested with other fields and `DateTime` fields are picking up `[today]` and numeric fields are picking up "1,234.56".

I also tried setting `<Default></Default>` on the fields with no luck.

Any idea on where these values are coming from and how to set them to empty?

[image]

Comment: Check the site columns in the UI to see if they have default values specified.

Comment: @PirateEric: Definitely not since these are all custom fields and, as mentioned, I've tried setting the default value to an empty string.